# Why does iTunes and my iPhone not agree on how much free space I have on my iPhone?

Tags: itunes, iphone, storage

Ok so I have a 32gb iPhone 4s that is updated all the way. When I plug it into my computer (PC) and run iTunes it (iTune) will tell me that I have a ton of free space on my phone howeer, when I look at my phone it says I barely have a Gig of free space. I am really confused. I don't have a lot apps or a lot pictures anymore so how do I sync iTunes with my iPhone so it will tell me how much storage space I have?

Comment: What version of iTunes are you using? Can you post screenshots of your Usage screen on iPhone and the usage bar in iTunes?

Comment: Sync it, back it up, restore it is the usual solution. Forces everything to have a rethink.

Answer (score 1):

This happens from time to time. You can get a recalculation of the space by connecting to iTunes and power cycling the phone.

If that doesn't work, you may need to back up the phone and erase it and set up as new - seeing that the space used is correct, then erase a second time and restore the backup.